# How to make JqGrid always have empty row at bottom?

Tags: jqgrid, grid, row

I'm using JqGrid with inline editing and i dont use navigation, pager or footer. I want to add empty row at the bottom to added. I mean empty row will be always there after editing an exsiting row, after adding new row.

I added row in loadComplete event, but i just adds empty row at beginning not anymore.

```
jQuery("#tableContents").jqGrid({
    postData: { orderId: '139358' },
    mtype: "POST",
    url: "test.asmx/GetContents",
    datatype: "json",
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: true, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
    colNames: ['Master Content ID', 'Description Of Goods', 'No Of Items', 'Total Value for Customs', 'Weight', 'Track No'],
    colModel: [
             {
                 name: 'master_content_id', index: 'master_content_id', width: 60, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }
             },
             {
                 name: 'content', index: 'content', width: 60, sorttype: "string", editable: true, edittype: "text",
                 editrules: {
                     required: true
                 }
             },
             {
                 name: 'piecesInt', index: 'piecesInt', width: 90, align: "right", sorttype: "int", editable: true,
                 editrules: {
                     number: true,
                     required: true
                 }
             },
             {
                 name: 'value', index: 'value', width: 100, align: "right", sorttype: "float", editable: true,
                 editrules: {
                     required: true
                 }
             },
             {
                 name: 'weight', index: 'weight', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", editable: true,
                 editrules: {
                     required: true
                 }
             },
             {
                 name: 'track_no', index: 'track_no', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "string", editable: true
             },
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    //pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    regional: 'tr',
    height : '100%',
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
    editurl: 'test.asmx/EditContent',
    loadonce: true,
    sortable: true,
    //footerrow: true,
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        var $self = $(this),
            // savedRows array is not empty if some row is in inline editing mode
            savedRows = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
        if (savedRows.length > 0) {
            $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
        }
        $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, {    
            keys: true,
            extraparam: { orderId: '139358', staffId : '111' },
            aftersavefunc: function (rowid) {
                alert("Saved");
            }
        });
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        var $self = $(this)
        $self.jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});
    }
});
```

How can we do that?

Comment: you wrote "empty row at bottom". It is not clear enough because other options of jqGrid unclear. For example do you use `height: "auto"` or you use fixed height? Why you want to have the empty row? Why footer con't be used instead? Just try to use `footerrow: true`. Moreover the code which you posted add empty row **always**. So after every sorting by any column you will have one row more. Is it what you need?

Comment: i use height: auto , i dont use footer or pager at the tabel bottom. I want an empty row in the bottom so user can add new record using that empty row. I use inline edit, so when i add "footerrow: true" , i cannot edit that footer row with inline editing. I want that empty row is not sorted.

Comment: I still don't understand the scenario which you use. To add new row and to start inline editing you can use `addRow`. You can use `position: "last"` option if you want that the row will be added at the bottom of the grid. The problem which I don't understand is **when and where** (inside of which callback and under which conditions) the `addRow` should be called in your scenario. I suppose that you try to implement some kind of input form and you want that the user add new rows. Probably you need prohibit editing of previously added rows on make some other restrictions.

Comment: in my grid i dont have add delete or save buttons, i do not have pager or footer, just coulmn headers and rows.my scenario is like that, 
suppose that there is no record in the row, there should be an empty row so that user can add his first row.

Comment: He will click on empty row to activate inline editing, input the values and then he presses Enter to save row.
Row is saved and again an empty row appears under the saved row before so that he can add his second record. 
He then selects the empty row agan to activate inline editing, he fills the values and enters again. Second record is saved and again a new empty row is added to bottom.This goes on like this.

Comment: What will be if the user click on previous added row? Should be activated inline editing? Do you start always with empty grid without any rows? Then the `addRowData` should be added after the grid is created and not inside of `loadComplete`.  In any way I don't understand your question. Where you have any implementation problems? If you start inline editing inside of [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) for example the you can use callbacks of `editRow` to make some actions (add empty row) on saving of the row. Did you try this?Can you post your current code

Comment: Oleg, i added my jqgrid implementation to code. Grid is filled with GetContents method, which can return records or not. If there are records returned there should be empty row below all rows, if there is no record comes from GetContents method, there should be 1 empty row on grid.

Comment: What will be if the user click on previous added row? Should be activated inline editing? I still don't understand your requirements because I find there inconsistent. **You should formulate the exact criteria when the new row need be added in the grid**. The current code do not what you explain. `aftersavefunc` should test whether empty row already exist and add it if required. You have to reload the whole grid probably or at least set correct rowid (from the database) for saved row. Usage of `addRowData` in `loadComplete` is wrong too. You can sort any column and will see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use jqGrid in the way which is opposite to the standard behavior. It's very bad idea. You will have to write a lot of code and have minimal difference to the standard way.

The main problem is: jqGrid hold **data** inside of the grid. You try to add an empty row **inside of the data** which is not loaded from the server, which is not in editing mode (like `addRow` do for example) and which is not saved on the server. So you try to use the grid in the way contradicting to jqGrid logic. It sounds simple, but it is really bad and the implementation will be complex.

I would recommend you to follow the standard way. You will have clean and simple code and the most of the users can use the grid intuitive. For example you can do add navigator toolbar where you add "+"/"Add" button with respect of `inlineNav`. The user will intuitively understand what need be done to add new row. The difference whether the user clicks on empty row at the bottom of the grid or if the user clicks on "Add new row" button, existing also at the bottom of the grid, is very small. After the click on the button the new row will be added and the user can insert the data. By press of <kbd>Enter</kbd> the row will be saved and by press on <kbd>Esc</kbd> the empty row will be removed. The code will be simple and it will do almost the same what you try to implement now.